# How to change variable valuein streambuilder with setstate?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code.  I want to change variable values in streambuilder. I tap on gesture, but nothing was changed. Variables keeping the initial value. How can I do this?

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
 stream: widget.isHome == true
       ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .doc(widget.postedUser)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .doc(widget.postId)
          .snapshots()
        : FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .doc(widget.postId)
          .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) 
        {
          var data = snapshot.data!;                              // This is variables
          Map gunler = data['Days'];                            // This is variables
          var isHold = data['Days']['${getWeekday()}']['isHold'];   // This is variables
          var day = data['Days']['${getWeekday()}']['day'];     // This is variables
    
    ...
     .....
      .......
```

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: days.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
       day = data['Days']['${index}']['day'];    //There I want to change values
       isHold= data['Days']['${index}']['isHold'];  //There I want to change values
      });
     },
  child: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
  height: 27,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.blue,
  borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  child: Center(
   child: Text(
     data['Days']['${index}']['day'], 
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
         ),
       );
     },
  ),
```

And next I want to show or use changed values in any widgets.

Comment: how about using a https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-async/StreamController-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when  `setState(() {})` performed, then it re-render the current widget, which will re-initialize and fetch the values from firebase again, so that's why `setState(() {})` updated values not getting.

Solution would to move `ListView.builder()` in sepeare widget, then perform `setState(() {})` which will then update the values in that new widget only.

Comment: Thanks. I am also didn't find another solution yet ))